# Editing footer name of a free imagehost script

Tags: html, footer

I want editing the footer name of Mihalism Multi Host, a free imagehost script.

I go to the `page_footer.tpl` and I see:

```
    <div class="page_footer">
        Powered by <a href="http://www.mihalism.net/multihost/">Mihalism Multi Host</a> v<# VERSION #>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google_stats("UA-1125794-2");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I edit it nothing change. On index.html I see:

```
<div class="content_box">
    This Website is Powered by <a href="http://www.mihalism.net/multihost/">Mihalism Multi Host</a>
</div>
```

But nothing.

Detail footer homepage:

[image]

Why the name not change if I edit it? I noticed index.html in every folder, also in folders where it is not necessary.
Suggestions? Maybe it's protected and not is possible change it?

Comment: Please [edit] to add the details of what is displayed, preferably the page source generated.

Comment: I have insert the detail. It's the content of page_footer.tpl but not change nothing.

Comment: Solved. I have wrong file. The right file was in another folder. :D